# Does equality hold in Frobenius inequality if $XZ=I$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrix-rank

The Frobenius inequality states that: $$\operatorname{rank}(XY)+\operatorname{rank}(YZ) \le \operatorname{rank}(Y)+\operatorname{rank}(XYZ)$$
My question: Does the equality hold in Frobenius inequality if $XZ=I$

Comment: @Mr.Coffee I mean: is $X=Z^{-1}$ a sufficient condition so that the equality holds

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $X$ and $Z$ are nonsingular matrices, the answer is "yes", because
$$
\operatorname{rank}(XY)=\operatorname{rank}(YZ)=\operatorname{rank}(XYZ)=\operatorname{rank}(Y).
$$
If $X$ and $Z$ are not square matrices and $Z$ is merely a right inverse of $X$, the answer is "no". E.g. try
$$
X=\pmatrix{1&0},\ Y=\pmatrix{0&0\\ 0&1},\ Z=X^T.
$$

Comment: how could one get $\operatorname{rank}(XY)=\operatorname{rank}(Y)$? I know that $\operatorname{rank}(XY)=\operatorname{rank}(YZ)$ comes from $\operatorname{rank}(X)=\operatorname{rank}(A^{-1}XA)$

Comment: @VIVID $XY$ and $Y$ have the same null spaces. Alternatively, they have the same row ranks.